# how to add slide panel without using JQM for mobile app?

Tags: javascript, jquery, slide, mobile-application, hybrid-mobile-app

Am building mobile app (phonegap) using jquery as a js library. Want to add slide menu that open on either tapping (in corner) or by sliding finger across. I could only find articles on jquery mobile but I dont want to use JQM cause I find all the default styles (theme, data-role ...) messy as I have to overwrite styles with my own CSS.
Is there any library just for sliding menu that open on sliding on touch devices other than JQM?

Answer (score 0):

There are a various open source projects for this out there. Just take Google for a search on "mobile slide menu" and you'll easily find dozens.

I personally prefer [Snap.js](https://github.com/jakiestfu/Snap.js) and use it on multiple apps in production. Its not that actively in development, but it does the job nonetheless.

Answer (score 0):

One of the library allowing to add side menu is AppFramework. The documentation for adding side menu is here: http://app-framework-software.intel.com/documentation.php#afui/afui_side but I would recommend to visit follow page: https://software.intel.com/en-us/html5/articles/templates-to-get-started-with-html5-mobile-app-development it contains demo and code for several features of AppFramework.